# How to redirect a user signed up with omniauth (Rails with Devise) to a specific page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, omniauth

Hi I just setup omniauth for Facebook and Google in my app by following this tutorial : http://sourcey.com/rails-4-omniauth-using-devise-with-twitter-facebook-and-linkedin/
Here's my OmniauthCallbacksController :

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def self.provides_callback_for(provider)
    class_eval %Q{
      def #{provider}
        @user = User.find_for_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

        if @user.persisted?
          sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication

          set_flash_message(:notice, :success, kind: "#{provider}".gsub(/_/," ").split[0...1].join(' ').capitalize) if is_navigational_format?
        else
          session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
          redirect_to new_user_registration_url
        end
      end
    }
  end

  [:google_oauth2, :facebook].each do |provider|
    provides_callback_for provider
  end

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    #if resource.email_verified?
      super resource
    #else
     # finish_signup_path(resource)
    #end
  end

  # def google_oauth2
  #   raise request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  # end


end
```

I want to redirect all the users who have signed up with facebook or google (Not sign in, sign up for a new account) to their user profile page with a notice asking them to change their username because I set the email as their username on signup. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after this line `sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication`
You can add a cookies value that this user is signed up using omniauth.

```
cookies[:oA] = true
```

In the `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` method check if the value of the cookie is true, add a path `username_path(resource)` for example.